# jQuery, count n position of element based on matching page/element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ok, so I need to be able to get the n (zero based) position of an element based on a mutual match between the page & element ID...

It's probably easier if I give an example (Assume the current page ID is `488`);

```
<ul id="work-grid">
    <li id="item-486" class="work-item"><!--/content--></li>
    <li id="item-487" class="work-item"><!--/content--></li>
    <li id="item-488" class="work-item"><!--/content--></li>
    <li id="item-489" class="work-item"><!--/content--></li>
    <li id="item-490" class="work-item"><!--/content--></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the list item with the matching numeric ID `488` is the third in the list (So would have an n value of 2).

The problem is, this grid appears on multiple pages (With different ID's) and the list is populated dynamically so I never know the position of the matching element. Is there a way that I can get it using jQuery and add it to the following snippet (Replacing `2` for the correct n position)

```
$('#work-grid').trigger("colio", ["expand", 2]);
```

This probably made little to no sense so if anything needs clarification please just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is what you want:

```
var index = $('#item-488').index();

$('#work-grid').trigger("colio", ["expand", index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your element appears once on the page, you can do:

```
$('#item-488').index();
```

to find out the index of the element. Read up on index() here: http://api.jquery.com/index/ The bit that applies to this scenario is:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bnF6h/

Answer (score 1):

```
var page = 488;
var a = $( "li[id$='"+ page +"']");
```

You can use this to dynamically select the item id based on the page id.

Applying it:

```
    var page = 488;
    var a = $( "li[id$='"+ page +"']").index();
    $('#work-grid').trigger("colio", ["expand", a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean jQuery's index() method?
http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
```